# Is it possible to reroll champion shards into a champion I already own?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've rerolled two sets of three champion shards and both times I've managed to get a champion I don't yet own, despite only having ~20 unowned champions.

So is it possible to reroll 3 shards into a champion you own? What happens when you own all the champions?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you already have all champions available, you won't be able to unlock a champion permanent. The feature would simply be disabled.

Comment: @Ksyqo It's enabled. You'll recieve some orange essence and a permanent champion shard.

Answer (score 7):

No, this is not possible. You'll always get a champion permanent of a champion that you do not have unlocked.

Comment: Not entirely sure about that tbh... Do you have a source on this?
If you have all champions you can still reroll champ shards into a random champion. You'll always recieve a permanent champion "shard".

Comment: @Jutschge My own experience and that of my friends. I've gained 4 champs this way while I only needed 7. My other friends have also gained only champs that they didn't have before.

Comment: The only exception to this that there may be is if you already own every single champion. There was a fairly large amount of discussion about this sort of thing on reddit when it first came out. One of the examples was that when a new champion comes out, and you already have every single other champion, you can just buy three random champion tokens from the store and combine them for a cost of around 5100 instead of the 7x00 for a new champion. This also works if you only have 6300 ip champions left to buy.

Answer (score 2):

As Riley said, you'll always get a champion that you don't have unlocked yet by this way. (I have every champions, and I unlock the last 2 champions by this way)

If you have all the champions and try to reroll three champions, you will get a shard and you will be able to reroll it again (so you lost 2 shards).
[image]
[image]

Comment: Well, technically, you get another random champion, but since you already got it, yeah, you just lose it.

Comment: "You will just lost them?"  What do you mean?

Comment: I wanted to take a picture to explain, but apparently they change it since I tested it.

Comment: @Bucky If you have every champion, there is no advantage to rerolling shards. You will simply be paying three shards to receive one random shard in return, losing the other two.