# Is it possible to reroll skin shards into a skin you already own?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've been trying to decide whether I should reroll some of my owned skin shards into a different skin or just disenchant them into orange essence. However, I was unsure if it was possible to reroll into a skin that I already own. If I just end up getting a skin I already own, it would be more beneficial to just disenchant them and buy a skin that I don't own.

The only posts that I've been able to find related to this question are  based around rerolling champions, for example [this Arqade post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/289246/is-it-possible-to-reroll-champion-shards-into-a-champion-i-already-own), or skin types (i.e. legendary, epic, etc.), such as [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/6illrz/reroll_into_random_skin_permanent_questions/). However, I've been able to find none relating to skins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-rolling 3 skin shards into a permanent will always give you a skin you do not own.

In the case you own every skin, it just re-rolls into a random skin and unlocks nothing.

https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/207884233-Hextech-Crafting-Guide

> Chests are random, and can contain content you may already own.
>
> We're looking at features to allow you to use the duplicate shards in
>   various ways. For now, you can re-roll shards to guarantee a piece of
>   content you don't own, or you can disenchant already-owned shards to
>   help you create permanent content from shards you don't own.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is this anecdotal or do you have a source?

Comment: @ChaseIngebritson Besides watching videos of people rerolling when they have all of the skins, I found a support article for you. I quoted the passage that you care about.

Comment: What about skins you do not own, but might not possibly be able to be gotten from shard, for example S2 Championship Riven?